# CSS Removing blue outline on HTML email href images

Tags: html, css, html-email

Would like to check what are the approaches that I can use to remove the anonymous blue outline when an email consist of an image `href` link? I have tried

```css
border: none;
outline: none;
text-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

but nothings works.

[image: outline]

Comment: What selector are you assigning these to?

Comment: @gh0st the `<a>` tag

Comment: try `text-decoration: none`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the border from the image:

```
a img {  
    border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the border by this (if you gave any):

```
Border:none;
```

Also try :

```
<img src="abc.jpg" border="0" />
```

If there is text decoration then remove it by this:

```
text-decoration:none;
```

If there will no changes appear then please you put your code on [JSFIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is not the in `a` selector but in `img` selector so you have to remove the `border` (which is set by default).

since this is for email I would advise you to set `border="0"` in `img`, instead CSS above head, just to be more cross-client as possible

something like this:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img" border="0" />
```

if you don't like this approach you can always do CSS inline

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img"  style="border:0 none" />
```

See more info about emailing tags/selectors [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)